# c# Can't reach registry value from Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I have a problem to read value from registry on my service application. I'm new on this service application part of .NET but I was using this code on my form application. There must be something different because it's not working in Service application. Anyway this is my code that I was reading normally :

```
 public string GetValue(string Name, string Path = "")
    {
        try
        {
            RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(DefaultFolder + @Path + @"\");
            if (RegKey != null)
            {
                object TempObj = RegKey.GetValue(Name);
                if (TempObj == null) return "-13003";
                Type T = TempObj.GetType();
                if (T.IsArray)
                {
                    string[] TempArray = (string[])TempObj;
                    string output = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < TempArray.Length; i++)
                    {
                        output += TempArray[i].Substring(0, TempArray[i].Length - 1);
                        if (i != TempArray.Length) output += "\n";
                    }

                    return output;
                }
                else
                {
                    return RegKey.GetValue(Name).ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "-13001";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "-13002";
        }
    }
```

Once I change my program.cs to call my class like console application it's working again then I put this back :

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
            {

                new TestAppService()
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

and it's not working.

So far I know that RegKey variable remains null after

```
RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(DefaultFolder + @Path + @"\");
```

this line but I don't know why.

I've googled a bit and found something like this

```
RegistryKey rb = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Default);
RegKey = rb.OpenSubKey(DefaultFolder + @"\" + Name, false);
```

But the result is same, my RegKey variable is still null.

All I want is reading a value under a path like this : 
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ServiceReadLocation\Values

Comment: What account is service running in?  CurrentUser doesn’t apply if you are running as say LocalSystem

Comment: In serviceProcessInstaller inside InitializeComponent method I've set account to 
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem 
Should I change it to System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User ? But then I have to know the user name and password right?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I try to do some work with the values I will get under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ServiceReadLocation\Values path inside registry. I am able to open this path and read from form application but I can't do it in service application

Answer (score 0):

The code `Registry.CurrentUser` and `RegistryHive.CurrentUser` when executed in a Windows Service `LocalSystem` won't work as you are expecting and is most likely the cause of `null` you are encountering.

MSDN:

> The registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER is associated with the **default** user, **not the current user**. To access another user's profile, impersonate the user, then access HKEY_CURRENT_USER

So I can see too options.

1. Arguably the easiest is to run the service as that user
2. Run the service as LocalSystem and *impersonate* the user and then access the registry when needed.  After reading, you can stop impersonating.

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution will work, I'll tell how I did. I changed my settings into local machine instead of current user because I don't want settings to per user. After that I have used RegistryKey rb = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Default);
RegKey = rb.OpenSubKey(DefaultFolder + @"\" + Name, false); OpenBaseKey instead of OpenSubKey and everything worked

Comment: Because I "was" using the current user registry key, then I realized(after a small speech with my boss) I don't need to put my settings into CurrentUser instead I started to use Local Machine, sorry if I insult I was just saying I don't know if your solution will work because I did not try it :) But if you say so then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm glad I learned that CurrentUser is just a shortcut, I will use basekey from now.